# Выборка из массива php согласно уcловию (даты)

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив(одномерный) с данными о прогнозе погоды, необходимо расфасовать данные по дням (сегодня, завтра, послезавтра). Пример массива:

```
31.03.2016      18:03   0.28    легкий дождь
31.03.2016      21:03   -1.75   легкий дождь
01.04.2016      00:04   -2.65   небольшой снегопад
01.04.2016      03:04   -3.42   снегопад
01.04.2016      06:04   -5.13   снегопад
01.04.2016      09:04   -5.34   небольшой снегопад
01.04.2016      12:04   -3.99   ясно
01.04.2016      15:04   -2.98   ясно
01.04.2016      18:04   -3.97   облачно
01.04.2016      21:04   -9.94   ясно
02.04.2016      00:04   -11.92  ясно
02.04.2016      03:04   -13.37  облачно
02.04.2016      06:04   -11.52  пасмурно
02.04.2016      09:04   -6.17   пасмурно
02.04.2016      12:04   -3.55   небольшой снегопад
02.04.2016      15:04   -3.71   небольшой снегопад
02.04.2016      18:04   -4.69   небольшой снегопад
02.04.2016      21:04   -5.73   небольшой снегопад
```

Структура массива:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 31.03.2016
    [1] => 18:03
    [2] => 0.28
    [3] => легкий дождь
)
```

в php завел переменные с датой сегодня, завтра послезавтра:

```
//ld - local_date
$ld_today = date("d.m.Y");
$ld_tomorrow = date("d.m.Y", strtotime('tomorrow'));
$ld_aftertomorrow = date("d.m.Y", strtotime('tomorrow+1day'));

echo "сегодня: ".$ld_today."\n";
echo "завтра: ".$ld_tomorrow."\n";
echo "послезавтра: ".$ld_aftertomorrow."\n";
```

Вывод:

```
сегодня: 31.03.2016
завтра: 01.04.2016
послезавтра: 02.04.2016
```

Как расфасовать (сделать выборку из массива по дням) данные из данного массива по дням, чтобы было так:

```
сегодня 31.03.2016:
31.03.2016      18:03   0.28    легкий дождь
31.03.2016      21:03   -1.75   легкий дождь

Завтра 01.04.2016:
01.04.2016      00:04   -2.65   небольшой снегопад
01.04.2016      03:04   -3.42   снегопад
01.04.2016      06:04   -5.13   снегопад
01.04.2016      09:04   -5.34   небольшой снегопад
01.04.2016      12:04   -3.99   ясно
01.04.2016      15:04   -2.98   ясно
01.04.2016      18:04   -3.97   облачно
01.04.2016      21:04   -9.94   ясно

Послезавтра 02.04.2016:
02.04.2016      00:04   -11.92  ясно
02.04.2016      03:04   -13.37  облачно
02.04.2016      06:04   -11.52  пасмурно
02.04.2016      09:04   -6.17   пасмурно
02.04.2016      12:04   -3.55   небольшой снегопад
02.04.2016      15:04   -3.71   небольшой снегопад
02.04.2016      18:04   -4.69   небольшой снегопад
02.04.2016      21:04   -5.73   небольшой снегопад
```

Comment: А `31.03.2016      18:03   0.28    легкий дождь` и так далее представлены в виде строки?  Или это всё одна большая строка? ... между датой и временем пробел?

Comment: дата и время одна переменная (тип дата, можно вообще unix timestamp, как угодно) просто разделены для вывода на экран, а легкий дождь - строка

Comment: Примените к исходному массиву `usort` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php  а далее в цикле просто выведите

Answer (score 1):

Если не применять никакие шаблоны и html, а в сыром виде выводить данные как они есть, то, в целом, получается так:

В начале к исходному массиву применяем функцию `usort()` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

`usort` - cортирует массив по значениям используя пользовательскую функцию для сравнения элементов.

А после этого выводим данные в цикле с применением уже своих дополнительных условий (пишем послезавтра/завтра и т.д.)

```
$arr = [
    ['07.04.2016', '18:03', '0.281', 'легкий дождь'],
    ['07.04.2016', '19:03', '0.282', 'смерч'],
    ['05.04.2016', '17:03', '0.183', 'лунное расщипление'],
    ['05.04.2016', '18:03', '0.184', 'взрыв солнца'],
    ['31.03.2016', '21:03', '0.185', '100 километровая комета'],
    ['31.03.2016', '01:03', '0.186', 'прилет НЛО'],
];


function strToTimeFunc($arr) {
    return strtotime($arr[0].' '.$arr[1]);
}

usort($arr, function($arr1, $arr2){
    $time1 = strToTimeFunc($arr1);
    $time2 = strToTimeFunc($arr2);
    if ($time1 == $time2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($time1 < $time2) ? -1 : 1;
});

// вывод данных    
$startTimeVal = date('d.m.Y', strToTimeFunc($arr[0]));
echo $startTimeVal.'<br />';

foreach ($arr as $test) {
    $time = date('d.m.Y', strToTimeFunc($test));

    if ($startTimeVal != $time) {
        echo '<br />'.$time.'<br />';
        $startTimeVal = $time;
    }   

    echo $test[0].' '.$test[1].' '.$test[2].' '.$test[3].'<br />';  
}
```

С учетом того, что у автора дата и время находятся в разных ячейках, сделал пример на основе этих данных. Конечно, чтоб упростить жизнь, лучше чтобы дата находила в одной ячейке.

P.s. если у вас `PHP7`, то `usort` можно написать вообще вот так:

```
usort($arr, function($arr1, $arr2){
    return strToTimeFunc($arr1) <=> strToTimeFunc($arr2);   
});
```